# Update Access Query using VBA

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to update an access query using VBA and changing the Like criteria in the SQL statement, but although I know that SQL code works, when running with VBA it continues to return the same information.

My code is below:

```
Function FTPCost()

    Dim database As DAO.database
    Dim query As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim strSQL As String
    Set database = CurrentDb

    Set query = database.QueryDefs("ftp_for_a_part_Query")

    strSQL = "SELECT ftp_for_a_part.PART, ftp_for_a_part.STD_TOT, ftp_for_a_part.DATE " & _
        "FROM ftp_for_a_part " & _
        "WHERE (((ftp_for_a_part.PART) Like '******')) " & _
        "ORDER BY ftp_for_a_part.DATE DESC;"

        'MsgBox strSQL

    query.SQL = strSQL
    DoCmd.OpenQuery "ftp_for_a_part_Query"

    Set query = Nothing
    Set database = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: "...it continues to return the same information..." - why would you expect it not to return the same information?

Comment: Sorry i have been manually been changing the Like criteria for now, this will work on a variable in the future

Comment: Still not clear what the actual problem is. Your code looks ok, except that `Like '600JSF2-1'` doesn't make much sense, `LIKE` is normally used with a wildcard search.

Comment: You could shorten the code by removing all references to the table except in the `FROM` clause - there's only one table so no ambiguity in which table the fields are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem. The fact the SQL code was not updating the Query was being caused by the query window being open. I did not understand that for the query to run the Query window must be closed.